# Suppose that $P(A$) is 0 or 1 for every $A \in F$. Show that if $X$ is measurable F, then $P[X= c]= 1$ for some constant $c$.

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Suppose that $P(A$) is 0 or 1 for every $A \in F$. Show that if $X$ is measurable F, then $P[X= c]= 1$ for some constant $c$.

I have  X is measurable F if $[ X = x]$ for each $x.$
But I have no idea how to relate with the probability, could you help me?

Answer (score 0):

Since $X$ is $F$-measurable, $\{X\le x\}\in F$ for all $x$ so $F_X(x)= P(\{X\le x\}) = 0$ or $1.$ $F_X(x)$ is an increasing càdlàg  function and has $\lim_{x\to-\infty} F_X(x)=0$ and $\lim_{x\to\infty}F_X(x)=1,$ so it must be a step function that jumps from $0$ to $1$ at some point $c$. Thus $X$'s distribution is an atom at that jump point and we have $P(X=c)=1$.

Answer (score 0):

Hints: Let $F(x)=P(X\leq x)$ and $c=\sup \{x: F(x)=0\}$. Show that $F(x)=0$ for all $x <c$ and $F(x)=1$ for all $x >c$. Now conlude that $P(X=c)=F(c)-F(c-)=1$ (where $F(c-)=\lim_{ x<c,x \to c} F(x)$ which exists because $F$ is monotonic.